# Make conditional GraphQL request based on node type value in React component with Apollo Client

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I am using React and Apollo Client.

Based on a node `type` value (`nodes.type`) from a GraphQL response, I want to conditionally make a GraphQL request to either below query `NodeTypeOne` or `NodeTypeTwo`.

```
// MyBlock.gql

export default gql`
  query NodeTypeOne {
    getNodesOne {
      nodes {
        id
        type
        title
      }
    }
  }
`;

export default gql`
  query NodeTypeTwo {
    getNodesTwo {
      nodes {
        id
        type
        title
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

So in below React component I want to *conditionally* make a GraphQL request based on the node `type` value.

```
import MyQuery from './MyBlock.gql';

const MyBlock = ({ data: myType }: Props) => {
  const { data } = useQuery<GqlRes>(MyQuery);

  const items =
    data?.items?.map((node) => {
      return {
        id: node.id,
        title: node.title,
      };
    }) || [];

  return data?.items?.length ? (
    <Slider items={items} />
  ) : null;
};

export default MyBlock;
```

How do I do this in a clean efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

As your query will target different resolvers, you cannot really create a single query from which you would target either the getNodesOne or getNodesTwo resolver.
useQuery on the other hand can take in parameter only a single, predefined query.
I would then go for 2 separate queries and use the apolloClient hook to conditionally call the right query:

```
// MyBlock.gql

export const QUERY1 = gql`
  query NodeTypeOne {
    getNodesOne {
      nodes {
        id
        type
        title
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const QUERY2 = gql`
  query NodeTypeTwo {
    getNodesTwo {
      nodes {
        id
        type
        title
      }
    }
  }
`;




import {QUERY1, QUERY2} from './MyBlock.gql';

const MyBlock = ({ data: myType }: Props) => {
const client = useApolloClient()
const [data, setData] = useState(null)

useEffect(() => {
  client.query({query: MyType === '?' ? QUERY1 : QUERY2})
  .then(({data}) => setData(data))
  .catch((err) => console.error(err))
}, [myType])

if(!data) return null /* or a loader... */

const items =
  data?.items?.map((node) => {
    return {
      id: node.id,
      title: node.title,
    };
  }) || [];

return data?.items?.length ? (
  <Slider items={items} />
  ) : null;
};

export default MyBlock;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several design patterns you can opt to solve problems. For your use case, the strategy design pattern will work smoothly.
For code reference, you can google for a bunch of examples.

These are from my reference:-

https://dev.to/wecarrasco/strategy-pattern-with-javascript-dha

https://gist.github.com/Integralist/5736427